# At delayed text in Python 3 how do I set it so it wouldn't return everything in a single line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from time import sleep
import sys

def print_slowly(text):
    for c in text:
        print (c, end="")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(0.09)

print_slowly("This text")
print_slowly("And this text")
print_slowly("End up in the same line with this one")
```

So these line will end up in the same line no matter what I do. I'm in Python 3 and I'm trying to define print_slowly so everytime I use it, it would print a separate string with the same aspects. Any ideas? (Newbie here)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a print outside the loop:

```
def print_slowly(text):
    for c in text:
        print(c, end="",flush=True)
        sleep(0.09)
    print() # add print here
```

Output:

```
This text
And this text
End up in the same line with this one
```

If you want to use `print` as the function name so every print does the same:

```
def print(text):
    for c in text:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(0.09)
    sys.stdout.write("\n") 


print("foo bar baz")
print("foo bar baz")
```

I would recommend just using the first example when you want to print, overriding print could cause you a lot of problems.

Comment: Not if you run it exactly as posted

Comment: How can I reuse this defined print_slowly later in my code? I want something like a delay I can use everywhere, if its once defined, is there a way for that?

Comment: @BotondHorváth Put it in a file and import from wherever you want to use.

Comment: Just use the function whenever you want to print